# Can I prevent a user to download a MS file in Sharepoint Online but can edit in browser and app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

I want a specific file to be edited in Excel or Excel Online (in browser). I don't want people to download it and re-upload so that it messes up the file, because there's like 30 people using it daily. I want to restrain them to only edit it directly and not download it and re-upload it.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download can be disabled as:
List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> under offline client availability section, Select No -> Click OK.

For re-uploading there is OOB method available. Disable the upload button using CSS/JS. But you have to take care of other scenarios as well such as Drag/drop files.